# Jquery conflicting with prototype magento - How can i separate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype, conflict

I can't seem to be able to separate jQuery from Prototype with my Magento website.

I've got it working on JsFiddle using changed tags etc but when i add it to my magento site, i keep getting uncaught syntax errors.

Page is at http://www.asg.co.uk/gadgetclinic/how-it-works

Code i'm working with is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// First hide them all

$j("#how-it-works .step").hide();

function fades($j.step) {    
    $j div.fadeIn(300, function () {
            if (!$j div.is('last-child')) {
                fades($div.next());
            }
            else{
                fades($j("#how-it-works .step:first-child"));
            }
    });
}

fades($("#how-it-works .step:first-child"));
</script>
```

HTML Code is:

```
<div id="how-it-works">
<img src="{{skin url="images/how-it-works.png"}}" alt="How It Works" />
<div class="step"><h3>Get your box</h3><p>We'll send a suitably sized, pre-paid postage box for your device.</p></div>
<div class="step"><h3>Post your device</h3><p>Safely pack your device in your postage box and return it to us.</p></div>
<div class="step"><h3>Repair in process</h3><p>We will update you if need be whilst your device is repaired.</p></div>
<div class="step"><h3>Get your device</h3><p>Your device will be returned using the service you selected.</p></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me systematically help put all the required $ tags into $j or whatever is needed to separate jQuery from Prototype?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your **jquery.x.x.x.js** file and add this to the very bottom of it: `jQuery.noConflict();`
2. Then for your custom jQuery code, use the following:

   ```
   jQuery(function($){
   // Use jQuery with $(...)

       $('#mySelector').hide();

       /* your jquery code....*/

   });
   ```

That is how I implement jQuery with Magento.  I prefer to use the `$` for the jQuery instance as it's clean and familiar.  The above code wrapper allows you to do this.

Comment: Getting closer! Now things seem to have hidden but i cant show them haha

Comment: That is most likely a problem with your actual jQuery code.  My method only outlines how to correctly run jQuery and Prototype on Magento in unison.

Comment: Okay, so can you please look at my code and be able to tell me what might be wrong? I'm not getting any errors in inspector now...

Answer (score 1):

Usually 
[jQuery no conflict](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) is used

Edit
So the best way for you is to use noconflict + 
        (function ($j) {
            ... // your code here
        }(jQuery));

Edit2 **3 examples how to use it**

1

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    // you can keep using $j
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});
```

2

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
    // or change $ above to $j
    $( "div" ).hide();
});
```

3

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {
    // Your jQuery code here, using the $
    // or just chane $ to $j if you want
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: So do I need to revert all the original $ tags that i changed to $j back to $, and put everything in a function wrapper that includes your $j above?

Comment: Sorry It's not clear from your edit on how to write it... I already have a script section that says var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); a few lines above...

Comment: How can it work if I said i didnt know how to write it? Your method wasnt clear at all. the other answer posted on here seems to be getting closer though

Comment: I'm trying to use method 3, and my inspector is telling me invalid token or unexpected token on line 83.. i cant see what its referring to though

Comment: 1st of all you have scope problem, don't use var in `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Bu that was added when i was trying to add something previously, and im pretty sure its working fine. ive had to delete it all now as nothing was working. what do you suggest to do?

Comment: I suggest you to wrap your code with `(function ($j) { ... // your code here }(jQuery));` as I told you before (see ex. 3)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the following:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
// or change $ above to $j
$( "#how-it-works .step" ).hide();

$('.step').each(function( index ) {
$(this).delay( index * 700 ).fadeIn();
});
});
```

A combination of several posts on here. Seems to be really simple and lightweight. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a way to make prototype, jQuery and bootstrap work without interfering with each other and without using `jQuery.noConflict()`. My layout setup (`page.xml`) was following(stripped for easier read):

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/jquery.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/bootstrap.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/responsive-tabs.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/clickable.js</script></action>
    <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/site.js</script></action>
</block>
```

I was getting errors like following:

> TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
>
> element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);
>
> TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
>
> element.dispatchEvent(event);

I did not want to change `$` everywhere. So, I made three javascript files as follows:

> **proto_to_temp.js** having following code:

```
var $tempPrototypeDollar = $;
```

> **after_jquery.js** having following code:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

> **after_all.js** having following code:

```
$  = $tempPrototypeDollar;
```

As you can probably guess already, the first script assigns current `$` variable (owned by prototype) to a temporary variable called `$tempPrototypeDollar`. Second script simply assigns `jQuery` to `$`. Third script assigns the content of `$tempPrototypeDollar` back to `$`.

I included these three scripts in the following order:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/conflict/proto_to_temp.js</script></action><!-- First Script goes just before jQuery include-->
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/jquery.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/conflict/after_jquery.js</script></action><!-- Second Script goes just after jQuery include-->
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/bootstrap.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/responsive-tabs.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/clickable.js</script></action>
    <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/bootstrap/site.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>buzzthemes/buzz-intro/conflict/after_all.js</script></action><!-- Third Script goes after all related code has been included -->
</block>
```

This solved all the problems for me and now jquery, bootstrap and prototype, all seem to work fine.