# Magento Checkout Calendar

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, magento-1.9, checkout

After install the Amasty Plugin Delivery Date on Magento 1.9.2.4, the customers was unable to select a day or hour on checkoutusing the calendar. I was researching on internet, but I didn't find any type of answer about this. Maybe it can be a calendar trigger problem, js, css...

Anybody can help me?

You can check the problem [here](https://www.magiadascestas.com.br/update_mc/checkout/onepage/).

Thanks.

Comment: try to remove the JQuery.noconflict.js  
$('delivery_info').show(); uses the $.. firebug or equivalent is your friend :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
Removing the $('delivery_info').show(); on deliverydate.js make the calendar appear but the days are not selectable. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think i gave you wrong advice the problem could be that prototype.js conflicts with jquery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661610/jquery-conflicting-with-prototype-magento-how-can-i-separate

Comment: Hi.
Checking this new link, i think the only solution that I have is that:

jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {
    // Your jQuery code here, using the $
    // or just chane $ to $j if you want
})( jQuery );

On my js, I have this:

if (countDD == 0) {
            $('delivery_info').hide();
        } else {
            $('delivery_info').show();
        }

If I remove 'else { $('delivery_info').show(); }', the calendar appear again, but the days are not selectacle.

Comment: Going to your second solution, if I use the solution below, only the days are not selectable again:

jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {
    // Your jQuery code here, using the $
    // or just chane $ to $j if you want
   $('delivery_info').hide();

})( jQuery );

What's I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.